# Lag with simple shared-element-transition using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide, android-transitions

I have a very simple transition between two activities, and sometimes, the image stops in middle, lags, flashes a black color.

I have used shared-element-transitions many times with Glide, but I can't make it not lag this time.

**this is the first Activity:**

```
val intent = Intent(this, MediaZoomImageActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(MediaZoomActivity.ZOOM_MEDIA_URL, submission.imageUrl)

val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
            post_image_parallax, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(post_image_parallax)).toBundle()

startActivity(intent, bundle)
```

**this is the second Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_image)
    postponeEnterTransition()

    back.setOnClickListener { finish() }

    val url = intent.getStringExtra(ZOOM_MEDIA_URL)
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
            .into(media_zoom_image)

    media_zoom_image.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
        override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
            media_zoom_image.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
            startPostponedEnterTransition()

            return true
        }
    })
```

**this is the layout for the second Activity:**

1. constraintLayout
2. -backbutton (ImageButton)
3. -image (ImageView)

**this is the animation:**

```
<changeBounds
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200" />
```

It's very simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.
The second image originally had some listener to use gestures, and I thought that was the reason, but commenting everything out still it does that lag.
The image in the first Activity is the target of another shared-element-transition with the same transitionName, can that be the problem?
Am I doing something wrong? Is it a problem with ConstraintLayout? Is there a problem with Glide?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead using **PreDrawListener**, using listener with glide would fix it. Looks like there is a timing issue

```
 Glide
            .with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
            .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    media_zoom_image.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    startPostponedEnterTransition();
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .into(media_zoom_image);
```

Make sure you remove

```
 media_zoom_image.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        media_zoom_image.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
        startPostponedEnterTransition()

        return true
    }
})
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated onResourceReady block. Give it a try please.

```
Glide
        .with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
        .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(media_zoom_image);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Call **postponeEnterTransition** as early as possible.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

postponeEnterTransition(); // Called it before set content. Try to call it before super.onCreate to see if it also works?

setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_image);
...
})
```

**UPDATE 3**

Optimize your images. There are some online websites or tools for it, or you can ask your graphic designer.

Also you can increase duration of animation to give time for smooth loading.

```
<changeBounds
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300" />
```

Notice that the listener in glide, runs before setting bitmap to view. Difference between Picasso and Glide, Picasso has callback parameter in into() method as optional, whichs runs **onSuccess()** after setting bitmap to view. So the execution which makes our shared transition is choppy (ImageView#setBitmapImage) already ran while postponed. Picasso has shining little bit more in this situation.

Comment: With this solution it seems to do it less or less often, but it is still there.

Comment: I don't know if it is a timing issue, cause it seem like it has difficulties with some images and some not. 
Also it only happens the first time, cause if I go back a do it a second time it is smooth, can it be a caching issue?

Comment: Its the time passing for loading image for a first time. It should work, i think problem is we have trying to redraw imageview while animating. I am gonna  update the answer. Can you try it?

Comment: Some images has lower file size or resolutions. This makes them load and draw faster. Thats why you are unable always reproduce it.

Comment: It got better, I saw it once, and I think it is my phone (I'm testing both on the emulator and on my Nexus 6p).
It lags at the beginning like if the image has to redraw and it takes a bit.

Comment: There is another problem now:  
If I delete the cache and download the image making sure it's not memorized, it freezes for 1 or 2 seconds waiting for the startPostponedEnterTransition.
I'm transitioning from a thumbnail to a bigger image where the user can use gestures to zoom-in, in the second activity.

Unfortunately I cannot optimize the images as I'm dowloading them from the internet, the one example I'm testing is 1080x800.

Do you think I have to downsample them as I go? create a downsampling ImageView? I don't know how to balance it, so the user doesn't see grain zooming in.

Comment: We are freezing the ui for shared element transition. The best thing we can do it reduce the file sizes of original images by tools and creating our thumbnails from original (full-sized) ones and the best trick would be while creating thumbnails from original sizes, we cache original images :) When user wants to see full image, it is already cached! Smooth as it can be

Comment: What if I use a thumbnail, with the same image .with thumbnail(0.1f), will that work? I'd have to change the listener and go back to preDrawListener, right?

Comment: Yes it will work. Also you need to make sure DiskCacheStrategy option let you save original one, not the generated thumbnail. Then you are done with this code :d